# Accessing scope of a variable once declared outside class

Tags: java, variables, scope

Hi I have this code to get shortest word in a string:-

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Kata {
 public static int findShort(String s) {

   int shortestLocation = null;
   String[] words = s.split("");
   int shortestLength=(words[0]).length();
   for(int i=1;i<words.length;i++){
     if ((words[i]).length() < shortestLength) {
         shortestLength=(words[i]).length();
         shortestLocation=shortestLength;
     }
   }
   int p = shortestLocation;
   return p;
 }
}
```

It returns error that variable shortestLocation cannot be converted to int:-

```
java:6: error: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int
int shortestLocation = null;
```

My question is how do you access the scope of a variable,like in this case I know what is wrong. The variable shortest location is defined outside the scope of if statement,hence it considers only the value with which it was initialized.

How do i make it so that the initial value is changed to the if-statement value. It is a scope problem,please help i am beginner.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. And no, this has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: You cannot assign null into primitive type int. This has nothing to do with scope

Comment: I fixed it and changed the value to 0,but now it returns 0 all the time. My variable's value never changes to the one returned after if statement.

Comment: If your shortest length starts at 0 how are you ever going to find a word that has less characters than that? "Is the length of this word less than 0?" - No, it never is so the variable never changes so it's always 0. Your starting shortest length should be the length of the 1st word.

Comment: why do you initialize p? just return shortestLocation. #off topic

Comment: there is a lot wrong here man... seriously i want to give you tips.. but this is ...

Comment: @Jason Well, arguably, creating the temporary can help if you ever need to debug it so you can check the value before it's returned. Debuggers I've used don't seem to be able to get the value that's given directly to a `return`.

Comment: Also FYI - If words[0] is the shortest String of the words array then your `if` wont ever equate to true and therefore shortestLocation would remain set to whatever it was before the `if`...

Comment: This is just an example,i am new and i am trying things. My actual problem is i am not understanding scope and controlflow. Ignore the p and Let me put it this way. When i return shortestLocation,which variable will i get? One that i initialized or the one from the if statement. How do i access variable from that if statement and use it anywhere else in the class? If you can help me improve then please do.

Comment: @TonyKennah There have been occasions where i want to access a variable from inside a for loop or if statement but i never get the desired value instead i get the value i instantiated the variable with.

Comment: scope is a much different question

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. I have got it working. I eliminated `shortestLocation` completely and used `return shortestLength` directly instead and it worked. But my confusion still remains,if i initialize a variable like x, and change it's value in a seperate codeblock e.g conditional statement or a loop. When i return it outside that conditional block will it return the value i initialized or the value would've changed after going through that conditional statement? To simply put Is it changed everywhere or just inside the scope of that if statement?

Comment: in all honesty, that is a much larger/different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Kata {
public static int findShort(String s) {

int shortestLocation = null;
```

this ^^ line needs to be initialized to an integer... not 'null' 0 is fine

```
String[] words = s.split("");
int shortestLength=(words[0]).length();
    for(int i=1;i<words.length;i++){
```

your problem starts here ^^ you never iterate through all of the words as you stop at `i<words.length` the problem with that is you begin at i=1. for loops work like this for (begin here; **until this is not met**; do this each time) when `i=words.length` the condition is no longer met.

```
   if ((words[i]).length() < shortestLength) {
        shortestLength=(words[i]).length();
       shortestLocation=shortestLength;
    }

    }

 int p= shortestLocation;
```

No need to initialize p here... just return shortest location.

```
 return p;
        }
  }
```

that leaves the final code like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Kata {
public static int findShort(String s) {

int shortestLocation = 0;
String[] words = s.split("");
int shortestLength=(words[0]).length();
    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
      if ((words[i]).length() < shortestLength) {
        shortestLength=(words[i]).length();
        shortestLocation=shortestLength;
      }

    }

 return shortestLocation;
        }
  }
```

**Keep in mind, to get a 'good' result it HEAVILY weighs on the words list**

As pointed out in the comments initializing your original 'int p' could help with debugging.

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. I have got it working. I eliminated `shortestLocation`  completely and used `return shortestLength` directly instead and it worked. But my confusion still remains,if i initialize a variable like x, and change it's value in a seperate codeblock e.g conditional statement or a loop. When i return it outside that conditional block will it return the value i initialized or the value would've changed after going through that conditional statement? To simply put Is it changed everywhere or just inside the scope of that if statement?

Comment: if the variable is initialized inside of the loop it is scope bound to that loop, you did not do that though, you had your variable initialized outside, therefore the scope was class related. look into **static scoping rules**

Comment: @enemy123 anything else i can clarify?

Comment: Yes thanks for the help, so the value that i initialize outside the loop will be accessible everywhere in class. But if that value is used in a let's say if statement and i change it's value. For example `x=1` now if i use it in if statement it's value is changed to suppose n. Now what is it's value? If i access it outside that loop now,is it still 1 or has it been replaced by n? Sorry if i have been confusing just a beginner.

Comment: If it is initialized within the ___ it is a ___ variable. class, loop, method.. etc As long as methods have the access specifiers in place it may by accessed.  seriously for java read up on static scoping rules and variable lifecycles.

Comment: Will do and thanks again for the help can't thank you enough.